# A question using mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ be twice-differentiable (i.e. $f'$ and $f''$ exist) on $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$. Prove that there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$4\cdot|f(b)-f(a)|/(b-a)^2 \leq |f''(c)|$.

I guess the prove uses the mean value theorem but I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

$(1)$ There is $c\in(a,b)$ so that $\cfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$

$(2)$ There is $d\in (a,c)$ so that $\cfrac{f'(c)-f'(a)}{c-a}=f''(d)$

$(3)$ There is $e\in (c,b)$ so that $\cfrac{f'(b)-f'(c)}{b-c}=f''(e)$

$(4)$ Let $g=d$ if $|f''(d)\ge f''(e)|$ and $e$ otherwise. We have $|f''(g)|=\max(|f''(d)|,|f''(e)|)$

---

$$\begin{array}{ll}\cfrac{|f(b)-f(a)|}{(b-a)^2}&\underset{(1)}{=}\cfrac{|f'(c)|}{b-a}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{2}\cfrac{2|f'(c)|}{b-a}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{2}\cfrac{|f'(c)-f'(a)|+|f'(b)-f'(c)|}{b-a}\\
&=\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{c-a}{b-a}\cfrac{|f'(c)-f'(a)|}{c-a}+\cfrac{c-a}{b-a}\cfrac{|f'(b)-f'(c)|}{b-c}\right)\\
&\underset{(2),(3)}{=}\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{c-a}{b-a}|f''(d)|+\cfrac{b-c}{b-a}|f''(e)|\right)\\
&\underset{(4)}{\le}\cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{c-a}{b-a}|f''(g)|+\cfrac{b-c}{b-a}|f''(g)|\right)\\
&=\cfrac{1}{2}|f''(g)|\end{array}$$

I'm missing a $\cfrac{1}{2}$ somewhere apparently...

Comment: Your derivation is correct, but leads to a weaker inequality than the one asked for. Do have a look at the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557599/prove-that-f-xi-geqslant-frac4fa-fbb-a2 of which this current one is a duplicate.