# $f(0)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ implies $\max|f''|\geq 4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Let $f\in C^2(\mathbb [0,1],\mathbb [0,1])$ such that
>
> $f(0)=f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ and $f(1)=1$
>
> Prove that  $\max_{[0,1]}|f''|\geq 4$

**Progress**

Applying Cauchy mean value theorem three times proves the existence of

- $\xi\in (0,1)$ such that $f'(\xi)=1$
- $\eta\in(\xi,1)$ such that $\displaystyle f''(\eta)=\frac{1}{\xi-1} <0$
- $\beta\in(0,\xi)$ such that $\displaystyle f''(\beta)=\frac{1}{\xi}>0$

If $\displaystyle \xi\leq \frac{1}{4}$ or $\displaystyle \xi\geq \frac{3}{4}$, we're done.

What about other cases ?

I haven't used the continuity of $f''$ yet...

Comment: just a vague idea but tricks of the sort $f(1) = f(0) + \int_0^1 f'(x)dx = f(0) + \int_0^1 \big( f'(0) + \int_0^x f''(t) dt \big) dx $ possibly applied to an other function like $g(x) = f(x)(1-x)$ can be worth giving a try.

Comment: Simpler proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910707/386889). $C^2$ not needed. Twice differentiable sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$f(1)=\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)f''(t)dt.$$
So
$$1\leq \left(\int_0^1\left\vert \frac{1}{2}-t\right\vert dt\right)\cdot \sup_{[0,1]}|f''|=\frac{1}{4} \sup_{[0,1]}|f''|.$$
and the desired conclusion follows.

Comment: This is very elegant !

Answer (score 6):

Assume $|f''(x)|\le 4-\epsilon$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ with some $\epsilon>0$.
Then for $x\in[0,1]$
$$
|f'(x)| \le  \int_0^x |f''(t)|dt \le (4-\epsilon)x
$$
and
$$
|f'(x)| \le \int_x^1 |f''(t)|dt \le (4-\epsilon)(1-x).
$$
This proves $|f'(x)| \le (4-\epsilon) \min(x,1-x)$. Then
$$
|f(1)|\le \int_0^1 |f'(x)|dx  \leq \int_0^{1/2} (4-\epsilon)x dx + \int_{1/2}^1 (4-\epsilon)(1-x)dx= \frac{4-\epsilon}4<1,
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Very nice. I fixed some notations and a typo.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT:** Suppose that $f''(x)<4$ for $0\le x\le 1/2$ and, symmetrically, that $f''(x)>-4$ for $1/2\le x\le 1$.

Comment: Could you please explain why we are allowed to assume this? Couldn't $|f''(x)| < 4$ be satisfied in patches throughout $[0,1]$. Thanks!

Comment: @MathMan Write down carefully what you mean. My assumptions do not eliminate anything with $|f’’|<4$.

Comment: I am sorry,I still don't get it. Could you please explain this?

Comment: @MathMan. To address your question, consider that Dr. Shifrin's proof by contradiction amounts to showing that the following statement produces a contradiction: $$\forall x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \lt 4 \text{ and } \forall x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \gt -4$$. Because this produces a contradiction, the statement is false and its negation is true:

$$\exists x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \geq 4 \text{ or } \exists x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \leq -4$$

Now, this statement can be compressed into the following statement:

$$\exists x \in [0,1] \left|f''(x)\right| \geq 4$$ 

I was confused at first, too.

Comment: Typically, proof by contradictions work by assuming the negation of a consequent and deriving a contradiction. i.e. to prove $\psi \rightarrow \phi$, we'll show $\psi \land \neg\phi$ results in a contradiction. The problem is written as:

"IF $f$ is twice differentiable with$f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, THEN there is some $x \in (0,1)$ such that $|f''(x)|\geq 4$ " $\quad (\dagger)$.

Assigning the antecedent to $\psi$ and the consequent to $\phi$, our proof by contradiction would thus read as:

Comment: "$f$ is twice differentiable with$f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$ **AND** for all $x \in (0,1)$, $|f''(x)| \lt 4$."

Now, the way that Dr. Shifrin has started his contradiction, it's not at all clear why $\forall x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \lt 4 \text{ and } \forall x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \gt -4$ is valid. In fact, the following statement is, in general, false (for the reason you pointed out):

$$\forall x \in (0,1): |f''(x)| \lt 4 \rightarrow \forall x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \lt 4 \text{ and } \forall x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \gt -4$$

The trick is to **rewrite** $(\dagger)$ as:

Comment: "IF $f$ is twice differentiable with$f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, THEN $\exists x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \geq 4 \text{ or } \exists x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \leq -4 \quad (\dagger\dagger)$."

So, really, the proof by contradiction routine is actually taking place at a "sublevel" argument. 

Once we have proven $(\dagger \dagger)$, we can easily show that: 

$\left(\exists x \in [0,1/2] f''(x) \geq 4 \text{ or } \exists x \in [1/2,1] f''(x) \leq -4 \right) \rightarrow \exists x \in [0,1] \left|f''(x)\right| \geq 4$.

Comment: Note that $\left[(A \rightarrow B) \land (B \rightarrow C)\right]\rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)$. Therefore, we conclude: 

"IF $f$ is twice differentiable with$f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, THEN $\exists x \in [0,1] \left|f''(x)\right| \geq 4$"