# Prove that $|f ''|\ge 4$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f(x)\in C^2:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfy $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, prove that:
$$\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f''(x)|\ge4$$

By using Taylor series I can prove that $\max_{x\in[0,1]}|f''(x)|\ge2$, but I cannot go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint: estimate $\vert f(1/2)-f(0)\vert$ and $\vert f(1)-f(1/2)\vert$ just like you presumably did (using Taylor's formula), and then use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I don't think it can be that different! Awesome! How can you come up with that?

Comment: If you keep dividing $[0,1]$ into smaller pieces (more than $2$), would you have a better bound?

Comment: @Mr.T I would say that to come up with that, you can try to find an approach that "preserves the symmetry between $0$ and $1$". With this in mind, it is "natural" to introduce $1/2$. (Perhaps this is not very convincing...) I don't think you can get a better bound, but I've no example showing the optimality right now.

Comment: It was a multiduplicate.