# Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Show that if $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then $|f'(c)|\ge \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I have tried to solve the below problem, and think I went very close to getting the answer but have been unsuccessful so far. Below is the problem and my proof.

Suppose that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable. Show that if $f(a)=f(b)=0$, then

$$|f'(c)|\ge \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ for some $c\in (a,b)$.

Proof: Let $M=sup\{|f'(x)|:x\in (a,b)\}$. THen if $M=\infty$, the inequality clearly holds for some $c\in (a,b)$. So assume $M$ is finite.

Then for any $x\in [a,\frac{a+b}{2}]$, by the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $c_x\in (a,x)$ such that

$$f(x)=f(x)-f(a)=f'(c_x)(x-a)\le M(x-a)$$. 
Also for any $x\in [\frac{a+b}{2},b]$ by the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $d_x\in (x,b)$ such that

$$f(x)=f(x)-f(b)=f'(d_x)(x-b)=-f'(d_x)(b-x)\le M(b-x)$$.

So we have $\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^{(a+b)/2}f(x)dx+\int_{(a+b)/2}^b f(x)dx\le M\int_a^{(a+b)/2}(x-a)dx+M\int_{(a+b)/2}^b(b-x)dx=\frac{M}{2}(\frac{b-a}{2})^2+\frac{M}{2}(\frac{b-a}{2})^2=M(\frac{b-a}{2})^2.$

Hence, we have $M\ge \frac{4}{(b-a)^2}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

However, since $M$ is only the supremum of the set $\{|f'(x)|:x\in (a,b)\}$, this does not guarantee that there is some $c\in (a,b)$ which satisfies the inequality.

How can I solve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or solutions.

Comment: In fact, you have (unless $M = 0$) a strict inequality $$M > \frac{4}{(b-a)^2} \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$ So that suffices.

Comment: Why do we have the strict inequality?

Comment: if $M$ is not attained in $(a,b)$, then for every $x\in[a, (a+b)/2]$ you have $f(x) < M(x-a)$. Now, exploit that $f$ is continuous to obtain a strict inequality for the integrals.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557599/prove-that-f-xi-geqslant-frac4fa-fbb-a2 The role of $f(x)$ in the current question is same as the role of $f'(x)$ in the linked question.