# Prove that $|f''(x)| \geq 4$ for some $x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem:** Prove that if $f$ is a twice differentiable function with $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f'(0)=f'(1)=0$, then $|f''(x)| \geq 4|$ for some $x \in [0, 1]$.

I tried to get a contradiction from $-4 < f''(x) < 4$ by integrating the inequality from $0$ to $1$, but got nothing useful.
Please help.

Comment: Or this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557599/prove-that-f-xi-geqslant-frac4fa-fbb-a2.